# How to check for a sequence of string values in pandas dataframe and output the subsequent

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to check for the sequence of B-B-B in the dataframe.

```
d = {'A': ['A','B','C','D','B','B','B','A','A','E','F','B','B','B','F','A','A']}
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

array = []
seq = pd.Series(['B', 'B', 'B'])

for i in testdf.index:
    
    if testdf.A[i:len(seq)] == seq:
        
        array.append(testdf.A[i:len(seq)+1])
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I get it working? I don't understand what's "ambiguous" about this code

My desired output here is:

```
A, F
```

Comment: I'm confused, how do you get `A,F`?

Comment: @Manakin I'm looking for the letter after the three B's occurring. B-B-B-A, B-B-B-F

Comment: Do you really need to use a Dataframe and Series ? (if that is an example or a more complex case), or could we do it other way ?

Comment: @azro It has to be a dataframe, yes, it's an simplified sample from a bigger project

Comment: It seems more like sub-string pattern matching...Take a look at KMP algorithm. And for the error part use `(testdf.A[i:i+len(seq)] == seq).all()` because `testdf.A[i:i+len(seq)] == seq` would give a boolean numpy array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `ambiguous` comparison comes from the fact that when you test 2 `Series` for equalty (they should be same size), a pair comparison is done and you obtain a `Series` with only `True/False` value, you should then decide if you want all true, all false, at least one true ... using `.any(), .all(), ...`

   ```
   s1 = pd.Series(['B', 'B', 'B'])
   s2 = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'B'])

   print(s1 == s2)
   0    False
   1     True
   2     True
   dtype: bool

   print((s1 == s2).all())
   False
   ```
2. To access a subsequence, prefer the use of `.iloc`
3. You need to use `[i:i + len(seq)]` and not `[i:len(seq)]` because this is a `[from:to]` notation
4. You need to use `Series.reset_index(drop=True)` because to compare series they must have the same index, so as `seq` if always indexed `0,1,2` you need same for sht subsequence you compute (because `testdf.A.iloc[1:3]` is indexed `1,2,3`]
5. Verify the length before checking the Series to avoid an Exception at the end when the subsequence will be smaller

You end with :

```
values = {'A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'A']}
testdf = pd.DataFrame(values)
array = []
seq = pd.Series(['B', 'B', 'B'])
for i in testdf.index:
    test_seq = testdf.A.iloc[i:i + len(seq)].reset_index(drop=True)
    if len(test_seq) == len(seq) and (test_seq == seq).all():
        array.append(testdf['A'].iloc[i + len(seq)])
print(array)  # ['A', 'F']
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over every row in the DataFrame, we can iterate over the much smaller sequence (Much beter when `len(seq) << len(df)`). Use `shift` + `np.logical_and.reduce` to locate the sequence in the DataFrame and where it ends. Then we'll `roll` to get the next row after, which are the values you want. (Modified slightly from my  [related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377959/check-pandas-column-for-successive-row-values/55378820#55378820))

```
import numpy as np

def find_next_row(seq, df, col):
    seq = seq[::-1]  # to get last index
    m = np.logical_and.reduce([df[col].shift(i).eq(seq[i]) for i in range(len(seq))])

    m = np.roll(m, 1)
    m[0] = False  # Don't wrap around
    
    return df.loc[m]
    # return df.loc[m, col].tolist()
```

---

```
find_next_row(['B', 'B', 'B'], df, col='A')
#    A
#7   A
#14  F
```

If you just want the `list` and don't care for the DataFrame, change the return to what's currently commented out: `return df.loc[m, col].tolist()`

```
find_next_row(['B', 'B', 'B'], df, col='A')
#['A', 'F']
```